# Transition circle radius in d3 to cancel scaling transition--works but timing is off

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

Here is some example code and a fiddle of it:

```
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
var r = 20;
var factor = 5;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")");

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", r)
    .style("fill", "black");

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 150)
    .attr("cy", 150)
    .attr("r", r)
    .style("fill", "red");

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", "scale(" + 1/factor +")")
    .attr("r", r*factor);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o1wzfas7/2/

In the example, I am scaling two circles down by a factor of 5 (which also scales their positions and thus moves them "closer" to each other) and simultaneously scaling up the circles' radii by a factor of 5.  The idea is that they'll appear to move closer to each other without changing size (as if I was changing their "cx" and "cy" attributes instead), but for some reason the scale transition and radius transition seem to go at different rates, so you see the circles get larger and then settle back to the initial size.

Does anybody know how I would do this using scale and radius transitions, but having the two cancel each other out so that the circles don't appear to change in size?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/o1wzfas7/3/)?

Comment: If you want them to move closer without changing size, why not just do that directly?

Comment: Reasonable question, @royhowie.  I have a scatter plot that I'd like to be able to zoom and pan within limits.  This does not seem to be elegantly handled at present in the d3 API (zoom limits are--pan limits are not).  Prior to trying to implement pan limits, I *was* simply changing cx and cy and life was good.  Now I'm doing something like what Mike Bostock does here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520  The long and short of it is that I now get to deal with scaling instead of cx and cy variation.

Comment: @AmeliaBR royhowie asked a similar question--see my reply.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ErikMadsen.  One of those cases where the simplified working example to demonstrate the problem (which is of course much appreciated) ends up trivializing the underlying objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to explain what's going on:

The problem is that the changes you are making cancel out multiplicatively, but transitions proceed in an additive way.

So for your simple example, where radius (r) starts at 20, the scale (s) starts out (implicitly) as 1 and you are transitioning by a factor of 5, the effective radius of the circle is r*s:

At the start of transition:

- r  =20
- s  =1
- r*s =20

At the end of transition:

- r  =4
- s  =5
- r*s =20

Now, the way you're thinking of it in your head is that the *factor* should transition from 1 to 5, but that's not what is going to happen.  The default transition functions don't see your factor, they just see that radius is transitioning from 20 to 4, and scale is transitioning from 1 to 5.

Therefore, at the midpoint of the transition, each attribute will be at the midpoint (average) of its start and end values:

- r = (20+4)/2 = 12
- s = (1+5)/2 = 3
- r*s = 36

In order to do what you want, you're going to have to create a custom tween, which directly transitions the *factor*, and then calculates the radius and scale from there:

```js
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .tween("factor", function(d,i){
        /* create an interpolator for your factor */
        var f = d3.interpolateNumber(1,factor);

        /* store the selected element in a variable for easy modification */
        var c = d3.select(this);

        /* return the function which will do the updates at each tick */
        return function(t) {
           var f_t = f(t);
           c.attr("transform", "scale(" + 1/f_t + ")" );
           c.attr("r", r*f_t );
        };
     });
```

Note that in your real application, you'll need to store the "start" value for your factor transition in a global variable or each data object, since it won't automatically be 1 when you transition to a different scaling factor.

```js
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
var r = 20;
var factor = 5;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")");

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", r)
    .style("fill", "black");

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 150)
    .attr("cy", 150)
    .attr("r", r)
    .style("fill", "red");


svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .tween("factor", function(d,i){
        /* create an interpolator for your factor */
        var f = d3.interpolateNumber(1,factor);

        /* store the selected element in a variable for easy modification */
        var c = d3.select(this);

        /* return the function which will do the updates at each tick */
        return function(t) {
           var f_t = f(t);
           c.attr("transform", "scale(" + 1/f_t + ")" );
           c.attr("r", r*f_t );
        };
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll have to muck around a bit to get this working the way I want in my real code, but this makes sense and is exactly the answer I needed.

Comment: I assume in the "real" code, the scale transform is happening on a parent `<g>` element, so you won't want to do it all in one tween function.  You can still use the idea of transitioning the scaling factor in a custom tween, and then calculating the attribute value, but you can use the [`.attrTween`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-attrTween) method, since each custom tween function would only affect one attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now.  I'm actually scaling the ~2000 circles individually, though there's no reason I couldn't rewrite things so that the circles are all members of a group, and I have thought I should probably do that.  Intuitively I suspect that scaling a group would be computationally lighter, but do you happen to know if this is actually the case (at least to any significant degree)?

Comment: I don't have any empirical data on rendering performance of individually transformed elements versus a transformed group.  I'd assume the group has the edge, but it might not be substantial.  However, I can say for certain that you'd be saving on the number of `setAttribute` calls (and the resulting parsing of the transformation command) being made by the d3 transition functions, which would probably make a difference if you have 2000 circles to update at every tick.

Comment: Yes, fewer calls would be good.  However, I suppose I'm stuck selecting all the circles at least to update the radius since as far as I can tell, the circle attribute r isn't something that can be inherited as a group.  (I'm still new to JavaScript and d3, so I'd like to be wrong about that!)

Comment: Correct.  `r` is considered a structural attribute, it can't be set by CSS or inherited.  There has been talk about moving some attributes of shapes into CSS for SVG2, but for now the general rule is that anything that defines the geometry of a shape has to be set directly on the element as an XML attribute.